# Integração Delphi/SendGrid

Tags: delphi, rest, datasnap, sendgrid

Estou tentando integrar uma aplicação Delphi com o `SendGrid`. Para configurar a requisição estou usando o `RESTDebugger`. Informo o

```
Header Authorization="Bearer" + [minha chave]
Content-Type = "application/json"
```

E o JSON com o *body*, contendo as informações necessárias, porém quando envio a requisição recebo a resposta:

> Permission denied, wrong credentials

Faço o mesmo processo usando aplicação do Postman e o processo funciona, será algum problema do Delphi?

Comment: Você está consumindo os dados do SendGrid em um WebService, certo?... desse uma olhada qual o método de autenticação que é usado, pois se ele necessita de um token.

Comment: Sim, a autenticação é feita através do parâmetro Authorization no header da requisição, com um token gerado no painel do SendGrid.

Comment: Sim, mas existem vários tipos de métodos de autenticação, se você visualizar lá no Delphi REST Debugger, tem o simples e o básico que é com usuário e senha, mas como é feito com token tem o OAuth e o oAuth2, selecionando um desses dois logo abaixo tem um botão para você abrir o assistente deles para configurar a autenticação.

Comment: Entendi... vou tentar...

Comment: Não tem muita documentação de como usar o REST Debugger com autenticação, sugiro pesquisar do modo manual, feito com RESTClient, RESTRequest e RESTResponse.

Comment: Unit de integração: https://gist.github.com/AndreAngelucci/dbe63815897afcbe29713ab50b43884c

Answer (score -1):

Se você estiver usando componentes RESTClient do Delphi, no caso seria TRESTRequest, TRESTClient, TRESTResponse etc que por debaixo dos panos o RESTDebugger utiliza, ao passar o bearer você tem que passar tambem o parâmetro poDoNotEncode:

```
.AddHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer dfsdkfjsldkfgjdflg', [poDoNotEncode]);
```